# Enable Data View Caching JSlink

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, list-item, jslink

I have Enable Data View Caching unchecked and when i firts go in to my list i select the items i want to set color on press the button (pic1) and then it looks like this (pic2) when i after that refresh the page the color is comeing back (pic3). So the problem is that i want that after you press the button the color should set direct.

And if you go to edit page -> edit web part -> and just press apply its works every time till you close the page and open it again.

What can be the problem?

[image: pic3]
[image: pic3]
[image: pic3]

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Site settings -> Manage site features -> turn off: Minimal Download Strategy